# how move into next tab using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a tab using HTML, jQuery and CSS.

I want to create a certain functionality.
When the user is in the last text box of `tab1`, if he presses the `TAB` key, it will move into the next tab.

To implement this, I'm doing in the last text box i am giving the class bcz id is already using for other purpose.

How can I do this using class?.

I'm using the latest jQuery and I'm not creating tabs using jQueryUI.
It's made through html, css and jQuery.
I don't want to use tab index.
I want to create it using jQuery.

```
 <ul class='tabs'>
                <li><a href='#tab1'>Tab 1</a></li>
                <li><a href='#tab2'>Tab 2</a></li>
                <li><a href='#tab3'>Tab 3</a></li>
              </ul>
              <div id='tab1' class=tabss>
                <ul class= "set2"> 
                    <li>  test 1<asp:TextBox runat="server"   /></li>
                    <li>  test 2<asp:TextBox runat="server"   /></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div id='tab3' class=tabss>
                <ul class= "set2"> 
                    <li>  test 3<asp:TextBox runat="server"   /></li>
                    <li>  test 4<asp:TextBox runat="server"   /></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div id='tab3' class=tabss>
                <ul class= "set"> 
                    <li>  test 5<asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="test5" /></li>
                    <li>  test 6<asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="test6" /></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
```

[This is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4n5fL/4/)
.

But in demo there is no text box.

What could be wrong in the demo code? 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 mistakes:

```
<ul class='tabs'>
            <li><a href='#tab1'>Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href='#tab2'>Tab 2</a></li>
            <li><a href='#tab3'>Tab 3</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div id='tab1' class="tabss">
            <ul class= "set2"> 
                <li>  test 1<asp:TextBox runat="server"   /></li>
                <li>  test 2<asp:TextBox runat="server"   /></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div id='tab2' class="tabss">
            <ul class= "set2"> 
                <li>  test 3<asp:TextBox runat="server"   /></li>
                <li>  test 4<asp:TextBox runat="server"   /></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div id='tab3' class="tabss">
            <ul class= "set"> 
                <li>  test 5<asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="test5" /></li>
                <li>  test 6<asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="test6" /></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

your id tab3 is 2 times on your page,
and your classname should be inside qoutes

Comment: I think you mean `#tab3`, and not `#tab2`

Comment: Also, how does this answer his question?

Comment: @RononDex 2 times the same id gives an error in tabs, tried it on the fiddle an when i change it, it works

Comment: @user3149053 change one `id='tab3'` by `id='tab2'` like in my code posted above here. i tried that in your fiddle, and it worked

Comment: i also want when user in last text box of tab1 when he press tab key i will move to text box of tab2

Comment: Erm @user3149053, you realize that your textboxes are asp tags and not html tags right? You should not be surprised if they dont work in a html file...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how can you define "user in the last text box of tabs 1".(focus, mouseover...)
But you can use trigger() function of jQuery to next tabs.
Example : When user is in the last text box of tab1, you can use

```
$("#tabs2").trigger("click");
```